# JQuery // After delete id event not trigger

Tags: jquery

I have a datagrid where I have cell Quantity and another one Price with a label at the end showing the result (price * qty). That's work perfectly. But I can also delete a row and thats when it stop working.

This is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/bizonbytes/SYwpy/24/

To replicate the problem:

1. enter numbers in each rows (you will see the result of price *
   qty)
2. Then delete row 2
3. now go to row 1 and you change the
   value and you will see the result but if you do it on row 3 it won't
   work

So my question is why Row 3 stop working.

As a business req I need to rename the id's to 1 and 2 and not leaving them to 1 and 3

**HTML is:**

```
<div class="row_table row_service_table" id="service_row_1">
    <div class="cell celldata cell_service_data"><input type="text" class="quantity_row" id="quantity_row_1" rel="1"/></div>
    <div class="cell celldata cell_service_data"><input type="text" class="price_row" id="price_row_1" rel="1"/></div>
    <div class="cell celldata cell_service_data"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete_service_row" id="delete_service_row_1" rel="1">Delete row 1</a></div>
    <div class="cell celldata cell_service_data">Result row 1=<span id="total_1"></span></div>
</div>

etc.
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".delete_service_row").click(function(){
    var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('#service_row_' + rowId).remove();

    // iterates through each of the elements matched by the selector
    $('.row_service_table').each(
        // i represents the index of each of the elements
        function(i){
              // sets the id of each of the returned elements
              // to the string concatenated with the expression 'i + 1'
            this.id = 'service_row_' + (i+1);

            $(this).children('.cell_service_data').children('.quantity_row').attr('id', 'quantity_row_' + (i+1));
            $(this).children('.cell_service_data').children('.quantity_row').attr('rel', (i+1));
            $(this).children('.cell_service_data').children('.quantity_row').attr('name', 'quantity_row_' + (i+1));

            $(this).children('.cell_service_data').children('.price_row').attr('id', 'price_row_' + (i+1));
            $(this).children('.cell_service_data').children('.price_row').attr('rel', (i+1));
            $(this).children('.cell_service_data').children('.price_row').attr('name', 'price_row_' + (i+1));
      });
});

$('.quantity_row,.price_row').live('change', function(){
    var rowId = $(this).attr('rel');

    // Lets update the total line
    var total = parseFloat($('#quantity_row_' + rowId).val()) * parseInt($('#price_row_' + rowId).val());
    $('#total_' + rowId).text(total);
});
```

Comment: Links are excellent, but you should always also [include relevant code in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  (I did this for you, just now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're remapping the `id`s and `rel`s of the two inputs, but leaving the `id` of the result span untouched! (Also not changing the text of the containing `div`.)

[See this fiddle that renumbers everything](http://jsfiddle.net/SYwpy/29/).

The changes were:

1. Added `<span class="rezLabel">` to the results row and gave the result-value span a class of `rezValue`.
2. Changed the renumbering code to:

   ```
   $('.row_service_table').each (
       // i represents the index of each of the elements
       function(i){
             // sets the id of each of the returned elements
             // to the string concatenated with the expression 'i + 1'
           this.id         = 'service_row_' + (i+1);
           var baseNode    = $(this).children('.cell_service_data');

           baseNode.children('.quantity_row').attr('id', 'quantity_row_' + (i+1));
           baseNode.children('.quantity_row').attr('rel', (i+1));
           baseNode.children('.quantity_row').attr('name', 'quantity_row_' + (i+1));

           baseNode.children('.price_row').attr('id', 'price_row_' + (i+1));
           baseNode.children('.price_row').attr('rel', (i+1));
           baseNode.children('.price_row').attr('name', 'price_row_' + (i+1));

           baseNode.children('a').text('Delete row ' + (i+1));
           baseNode.children('a').attr('id', 'delete_service_row_' + (i+1));
           baseNode.children('a').attr('rel', (i+1));

           baseNode.children('.rezLabel').text('Result Row ' + (i+1) + ' = ');
           baseNode.children('.rezValue').attr('id', 'total_' + (i+1));
   } );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to rename the ID `total_3` to `total_2` in your `each()`. The change event tries to update the span `total_2`, but that doesn't exist, only `total_1` and `total_3` exist.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you remove any row, you're also changing the `id`and and `rel` attributes of several objects. You don't have to do that. Remove the `$('.row_service_table').each` block and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

After you call remove(), it's not necessary to reset the identifiers! I've updated the fiddle, check it out.